# How can I automatically build multiple Eclipse Plug-In Projects as one Jenkins project?

Tags: plugins, eclipse, jenkins, maven

we're using Jenkins as our build server. We have a Project which is built out of Eclipse Plug-Ins, a core project and several other plugins. Building the Core on Jenkins and using Sonar on it is relatively.

Now we want to create a Jenkins build where the whole Project is being automatically built and tested by Sonar. Internet research showed to change the packaging to "pom", which can't be done because the Tycho plugin needs to have packaging set to "eclipse-plugin".

What are we doing wrong and how do you setup a project like this in Jenkins?

If any additional information is needed, please do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an "umbrella" Maven project with `pom` packaging and make all of your other project modules of this aggregator. In addition however the whole group of projects need to be accessible from your SCM tool as a single entity. If you are using Subversion this is easily achievable by means of `svn:externals`, with other tools I suspect you'd have to alter your configuration. I suggest you also check out whether there's any [Jenkins plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) that might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

For git, you can use the [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) feature to achieve the same as with svn:externals. See for example mylyn, which probably comes close to what you are trying to achieve:

```
git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this example directory layout:

```
+ParentDir
 -pom.xml
   +ProjectA
    -pom.xml
   +ProjectB
    +SubDirB
     -pom.xml
```

Contents of pom.xml in ParentDir should include the following:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
   <module>ProjectA/pom.xml</module>
   <module>ProjectB/SubDirB/pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

And when you invoke Maven on this top-level POM, it will add ProjectA and ProjectB to the reactor list to be built.

This can be adapted for similar projects, and the `<module>` tag accepts relative paths, for example `../../SomeProject/pom.xml`.